# Floated element "steals" width from a following block element inside a display:table container

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, drop-cap

I have a div that's "floated" to the centre with `display:table; margin:auto;` (green box)

Inside this, I have a `float:left` element (red box, which is not always present), then a number of `display:block;` "lines" (lime boxes). The application is poetry formatting with drop capitals and reverse indentation:

https://jsfiddle.net/nktj94gd/2/

[image]

The problem is that the floated "L" is "stealing" its own width from the lime blocks, rather than allowing the outer block (green) to expand to prevent the lime lines wrapping when they do not have to.

I'd really like to avoid having lines wrap when they don't have to, but I cannot set the width of the overall box (it could be from a few em to 100%) .Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an extra wrapper inside that I make slightly bigger considering the width of L

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  overflow:auto;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
.outer > div {
  width:calc(100% + 2.8em); /* 2.8em is an approximation of L width */
  transform:translateX(-1.4em); /* rectify the centring */
}
.dropcap {
  float: left;
}

.dropcap-inner {
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.line {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -4em;
  margin-left: 4em;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    <span class="dropcap"><span class="dropcap-inner">L</span></span>
    <span class="line">orem ipusm dolor sit amet</span>
    <span class="line">Lorem ipusm dolor sit amet dddd</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Annoyingly, the drop cap is both optional and can be of any size (or an image, even). Is there any way to do it without relying on the cap's size?

Answer (score 0):

you probably found some more practical solution to this a year ago, but this is a fairly obscure problem I ran into while *also* styling poetry, so I figured I'd post my solution in case anyone else needs it :) Hope your poem project worked out, OP!

I think probably most people use `<br />` and `::first-letter` or something and thus never run into the problem. It's ultimately just a problem of how to preserve intended whitespace (linebreaks mainly) with a pretty dropcap, which is niche, but falls apart quick if you're designing responsively and avoiding hard breaks. (I was using `whitespace: pre` because it had indented stanzas) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

### How to fix OP's issue: table CSS and wrappers (responsive, markup-dependent), see: https://jsfiddle.net/eja5mnuk/

- Stick the spans and the float in a container div
- Change `display: block` on the spans to `display: table-row`; since your outer is `display: table`, and you don't impose widths anywhere here, the 'table' will simply expand to accommodate both the float and the linebox
- Optionally, `display: table-caption` on an *inner* part of the dropcap (not truly necessary, but in OP's code so why not: https://jsfiddle.net/thn2x5zc/)
- Everything is integrated into a table formatting context, but we aren't getting unwanted collapse that messes up sizing

This is responsive and doesn't care what your drop cap is. It runs into overflow issues if the drop cap and poem are both too big, you can shove whatever behaviour you want on this bad case if you want (like `overflow: hidden` on the dropcap, controlling their whitespace/widths, etc....)

It does care about your container structure and margin collapse a lot, so if your code were different, you'd need a different `display` value, likely something putting table-row/table-cell on a block.

Of course this *does* have quirks relating to how browsers treat table elements by default, though - mainly auto-collapsed borders, like in a `<table>`.

### Method #2: `::first-letter` pseudo-selector, white-space: pre, margin/padding etc. (things other people might use) see: https://jsfiddle.net/3oghpj0w/

These things are all very janky/contradictory secretly, but since `::first-letter` is a pretty standard way to style drop caps, and marking up/styling your lines individually may be inconvenient, it is how I ran into the problem lol.

If it's `::first-letter`, we're using a block-level element to hold the poem text. The most basic way is just to apply `width: min-content;` to that block's container to get it to sort of take away the float's contribution (since it's larger). Then you can add `padding-right` to that container to re-accommodate borders, margins, etc. (If the margin between the drop cap and poem is 3em, add 3em back to the right.)

Fixes of this style do not re-integrate the float with the poem, so the *poem* will still have overflow issues. But it's sufficient for fixing simple alignment problems :)

### Some notes

- The float contributes size to the block e.g. via its margins - floated margins don't collapse, generally, which is part of our problem here. But the container won't expand for things out of flow, and thus the float pushes its siblings into overflow (poetry is highly sensitive to wrapping and whitespace)
- Ultimately, most ways the browser can calculate the size of text wrappers ignore the float (it's out of flow); everything skews towards occupying space along the inline and block axis (horizontal/vertical, here), based on everything's sizing, margins, wrapping, and other inline/block contexts, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display
- Tables are the ancestors of most responsive text framing

Sorry this is so long! A lot of conventional fixes break when you care about the shape of the whitespace and can't treat text as a block, which makes a lot of search results very inapplicable.